# Why is my command firing before my CheckBox is checked inside a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The regular DataGridCheckBoxColumn does not seem to allow commands so I decided to use DataGridTemplateColumn with a checkbox inside. The problem is my command is fired before the checkbox can be selected or deselected why is this happening?

my datGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridSpecifications" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyEntityList}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DB:CoreNamedEntity}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                <TS:PhotometricTypeSelector
                    DataTemplateOne="{StaticResource PhantomNameTemplate}" 
                    DataTemplateTwo="{StaticResource PhantomCountTemplate}">
                </TS:PhotometricTypeSelector>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Hidden">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Hidden}"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.HideCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Hidden}" IsEnabled="False"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

this is part of the commands code

```
private void HideCommandExecute(object param)
{
    InputsAccessor inputsAccessor = new InputsAccessor();
    var type = param.GetType();
    int id;
    string name = type.Name;
    var ParamId = type.GetProperty("Id").GetValue(param, null);
    bool ParamHidden = (bool)type.GetProperty("Hidden").GetValue(param, null);
    id = (int)ParamId;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Check the properties, does it cause auto-postback?

Comment: Show the code on the command

Answer (score 0):

The IsChecked property must have  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged or it wont be set until after the command is called.

```
     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Hidden, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     CheckBox.Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.HideCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
```